# How to pass an array of arrays into a function at JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

How can I define an array of arrays and pass that variable into a function so I can manipulate it at JavaScript?

As like:

JSP side:

```
object.method({ {"#id1",2}, {"#id2",3}...});
...
```

JS side:

```
var object= {
defaults: {
  idSelector: "#id1"
},
method: function(options) {
  if (options && !jQuery.isEmptyObject(options))
     $.extend(this.defaults, options);
     var that = this;
     var opts = that.defaults;
     //Try to reach every array step by step?
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions' variable that will get the values should be like that(JSON format will be used):

```
defaults: [{
  idSelector: '',
  faqId: '' 
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

use json data format .
Convert your object into json string in your JSP page.
Parse that JSON string in your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Here's **one of the ways** to do that:

1. Your servlet can return a text, representing a json dictionary. Here's the documentation of a JSON API http://www.json.org/java/
2. Your javascript client code can fetch this json dictionary, something like:

   ```
   $.getJSON('ajax/test.json', function(data) {
   var items = [];

   $.each(data, function(key, val) {
       items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
   });

   });
   ```

now `items` points to a bunch of `<li>` with your results

Comment: I will just pass parameters from javascript(at document.ready()) to my .js file.